# xamarin.Forms DataGrid with editor

Tags: datagrid, xamarin.forms, alignment, editor

I'm trying to embed an editor in a `Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid` cell using following code (inspired from [this sample](https://github.com/akgulebubekir/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid))

```
<ContentPage.Content>
<StackLayout>
<dg:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionEnabled="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
           RowHeight="70" HeaderHeight="50" PullToRefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}">
<dg:DataGrid.Columns>
<dg:DataGridColumn Title="Col. 1" PropertyName="Prop. 1" Width="0.7*">
    <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Entry Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
</dg:DataGridColumn>
</dg:DataGrid.Columns>
</dg:DataGrid>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Now that works ok, but the edited text is aligned top-left of the cell. So I go trying to use one of the following alignment parameters:

```
HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
<!-- or >
HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
```

But in both cases, I end up with text centered within the cell, but now, the editor doesn't expand (it seems as if I had padding)... And the result with either `Center`or `CenterAndExpand` is actually the same:

[image]

Could anyone help me get the desired result ?

EDIT: updated with full grid's definition

BONUS question: how to get rid of the editor's border?

Comment: Are you talking about Editor or Entry? Can you post your full axml with grid itself definition

Comment: It is entry, code is exactly as it is !

Comment: if you need help please provide full answer on my questions

Comment: @YuriS I've updated with the full ContentPage's content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
```

Bonus answer: To get rid of border you need custom renderers.

[image]

Comment: Seems that `Entry` doesn,'t have a bindable `HorizontalTextAlignment` attribute...

Comment: What do you mean? which version of XForms you are using?

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19637/how-to-set-entry-to-align-right